# Putting header name above the column names in r

Tags: r, header

I have two model data sets. I want to add model name above the column names.
My data is

```
    v1=matrix(c(

10.3935,    7.9407,
10.8185,    6.9148,
9.3935, 5.9074,
18.3296,    9.3704,
15.2296,    5.0148,
8.9408, 1.9407
), # number of rows 
ncol=2,              # number of columns 
byrow = TRUE)       # fill matrix by rows 
colnames(v1) <- c(" x1"," x2")

v2=matrix(c(
10.1873,    5.5098,
10.3935,    5.6692,
9.6848, 5.1348,
13.5287,    8.4864,
12.3317,    7.3237,
9.4486, 4.965
), # number of rows 
ncol=2,              # number of columns 
byrow = TRUE)       # fill matrix by rows 
colnames(v2) <- c(" x1"," x2")

cbind(v1,v2)
```

My desired result is

```
          model1         model2

         x1     x2      x1     x2
[1,] 10.3935 7.9407 10.1873 5.5098
[2,] 10.8185 6.9148 10.3935 5.6692
[3,]  9.3935 5.9074  9.6848 5.1348
[4,] 18.3296 9.3704 13.5287 8.4864
[5,] 15.2296 5.0148 12.3317 7.3237
[6,]  8.9408 1.9407  9.4486 4.9650
```

I cannot manage it. So I need help.

Comment: For what purpose do you need that? This is not a standard R dataframe/matrix.

Comment: Seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is this for printing or documentation purposes? If so please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: If you are just talking about printing to the console: `cat(rep(" ", 5), "model1", rep(" ", 4), "model2", "\n\n"); cbind(v1, v2)` should do it.